# Python: Memory leak?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, memory-leaks

### Query in Python interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> k = [i for i in xrange(9999999)]
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(k)/1024/1024
38
>>>
```

### And here - see how much it takes from RAM:

[image]

### Memory usage after statement `del k`:

[image]

### And after `gc.collect()`:

[image]

Why list of integers with expected size of 38Mb takes 160Mb?

**UPD:** *This part of question was answered (almost immediately and multiple times :))*

### Okay - here is another riddle:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys

>>> str = 'abcdefg'
>>> sys.getsizeof(str)
28
>>> k = []
>>> for i in xrange(9999999):
...     k.append(str)
...
>>> sys.getsizeof(str)*9999999/1024/1024
267
```

### How much do you think it will consume now?

[image]
<sub>(source: [i.imm.io](http://i.imm.io/P5Yq.png))</sub>

Size of `str` is 28, vs 12 in past example. So, expected memory usage is 267Mb - even more then with integers. But it takes only ~40Mb!

Comment: As a side note, if you are dealing with large numerical arrays, and memory (and I'm guessing performance?) are a concern, it might be worth looking into using NumPy.

Comment: Good question. I think that `getsizeof()` only counts the size of the pointers in the list, but the actual integer values are stored as `PyIntObject` structs in C, which each have a bunch of overhead like any other Python objects. I hope somebody with more knowledge of Python's internals (or more time to dig around in them right now) can post a more precise specific reply as a answer. :)

Comment: Your second example is completely invalid. You store one reference to the same string many times into the array. The string itself only consumes its space once - it is always the same object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sys.getsizeof()` is not very useful because it accounts often for only a part of what you expect.  In this case, it accounts for the list, but not all integer objects that are in the list.  The list takes roughly 4 bytes per item.  The integer objects take another 12 bytes each.  For example, if you try this:

```
k = [42] * 9999999
print sys.getsizeof(k)
```

you'll see that the list still takes 4 bytes per item, i.e. around 40MB, but because all items are pointers to the same integer object 42, the total memory usage is not much more than 40MB.

Comment: Beat by 11 seconds.  Good answer +1

Comment: Indeed - 38Mb = sum of all pointers to integers, and 12(size of Int) * 9999999 = 114Mb = size of all actual integers in list. 38 + 114 = 152Mb.

Answer (score 2):

### What is getsizeof()

At first I propose to take a look at what the size-of operator means. You can find the exact description in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys). I want to zoom-in on the following sentence.

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

This means that when you ask sys.getsizeof([a]) you don't get the actual size of the array. You only get the size of all memory that is dedicated to managing the list. The list still contains 9999999 integers. Each integer consists of 12 bytes which leads to a total of 114 MB. The sum of the memory dedicated to managing the array 32MB plus the sum of the memory of the data in the array is 146 Mb which comes a lot closer to your result.